# model looks weird when removing loose and merging by distance

Tags: modeling, vertices, normals

so I ripped these models from a game (legally) and they contain a whole bunch of loose geometry. problem is, when I remove all of it, the model looks very odd. playing with normal recalculation only gets me so far with getting the original look back. was wondering if I could get rid of this geometry while keeping its original look. cleaned-up model is on the left and targeted look model is on the right

heres the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1LcWRvcGA9M_27sqMB8PEZSTYPbglod/view?usp=sharing). textures are packed

Edit : the clean model is with the normals as fixed as i could get them. to see what it looks like without adjusted normals, duplicate the right model, go into edit mode, select all, Mesh > Clean Up > delete loose. select all again and Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by distance

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean, maybe try a Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: wow, I didn't expect the answer to be that simple. that fixes it